# Does git diff use only info in staging area?

Tags: git

In git manual for git diff, it says "this form is to view changes made relative to the index".  Does git only uses the info from staging area for the comparison? Is it accurate to say that internally the index (staging area) contains complete object info from the last commit snapshot (and whatever else is staged at the moment)?

```
git diff [--options] [--] [<path>...]
           This form is to view the changes you made relative to the index (staging area
           for the next commit). In other words, the differences are what you could tell
           Git to further add to the index but you still haven't. You can stage these
           changes by using git-add(1).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: the index contains complete object info from the last commit snapshot and whatever else is staged at the moment.

No: `git diff` in this format uses more than just the info in the index, it uses the content in your working tree as well, comparing the two.  This form of diff specifically compares your working tree to the index.  It reveals all the changes you haven't yet staged.

Comment: Does staging need to contain the complete object info or just the SHA of whatever HEAD points to?

Comment: You might understand better if you try `git ls-files --stage`.  The index is a table of references to blobs and the paths where that blob goes in your working tree.  Those files that are staged but not yet in a commit are actually still objects in the object database.  `git add` actually makes a new blob object in the object database for the given file, then updates the index to reference that new blob.